# Dynamically changing Textarea background image

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am tring to change the background image of text area dynamically my javascript code is

```
function load(){
selectedsecond=localStorage.getItem("selectedimg")
alert("after loading"+selectedsecond);

document.getElementById('notecontent').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' +selectedsecond + ')';
document.getElementById('myimg').src=selectedsecond;
}
```

this method is called on the onload method of body. The image backgroune(myimg) dot changed, but textarea background is not getting changed. Please give an idea
   Thanks in advance

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/8FrLN/

Comment: hey. i did the same coding. Not getting

Comment: Create another jsFiddle with your code as @Thariama suggested so we see what is different.